# Show sheet into which the value was entered when closing form

Tags: excel, vba

I have three buttons in userform S1,S2,S3(sheet1,sheet2..) which assign a value specified in the textbox to the first cell on a sheet.  How to do that after closing user form show sheet
into which the value was entered/last used sheet

```
Private Sub Zamknij_Click() 
    UserForm1.Hide 
    Worksheets("SheetName").Activate 
End Sub 
Private Sub Sheet1_Click() 
    Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value = TextBox1.Value 
End Sub 
Private Sub Sheet2_Click() 
    Sheets(2).Cells(1, 1).Value = TextBox1.Value 
End Sub 
Private Sub Sheet3_Click() 
    Sheets(3).Cells(1, 1).Value = TextBox1.Value 
End Sub
```

Comment: Use `Worksheets("SheetName").Activate` in the userform code, before closing the userform or in a general sub shows the userform.

Comment: Don't work
Private Sub Zamknij_Click()
UserForm1.Hide
 Worksheets("SheetName").Activate
End Sub


Private Sub Arkusz1_Click()
Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value = TextBox1.Value
End Sub

Private Sub Arkusz2_Click()
Sheets(2).Cells(1, 1).Value = TextBox1.Value
End Sub


Private Sub Arkusz3_Click()
Sheets(3).Cells(1, 1).Value = TextBox1.Value
End Sub

Comment: Don't put code in a comment, add it to the original question.

Comment: Erm... so you need to replace "SheetName" with the name of the target sheet. Based on the info in the question (limited though it is), I assume you know the name of the target sheet. In case it's not obvious: you can put the sheet name into a variable and use that instead of a literal string.

Comment: It is a simple problem, 1. I have value in text box 2. Press the button, for example "Sheet3" to assign textbox value   3.  Close form and after this I need to open  sheet  
into which the value was entered

Comment: Yes, and the answer is also simple. But you do need to read what I've written. Suggest also reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet

Comment: `Unload Me` will unload the form, not `Me.Unload`

Comment: As an aside (and while not asked): `.Hide` is not the same as 'Closing' a userform (as Hiding leaves it active in memory). Also you can use `Me` in vba code to refer to the containing object (in this case your userform). Thus, a normal 'Close' operation would be performed via `Unload Me`.

Answer (score 0):

Putting my comments into code: Here is one possible way to implement what I think it is you're trying to do.

```
Private Sub Zamknij_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub Sheet1_Click()
    ApplyToSheet Worksheets(1)
End Sub
Private Sub Sheet2_Click()
    ApplyToSheet Worksheets(2)
End Sub
Private Sub Sheet3_Click()
    ApplyToSheet Worksheets(3)
End Sub

Sub ApplyToSheet(wsSheet As Worksheet)
    With wsSheet
        .Activate
        .Cells(1, 1) = TextBox1.Value
    End With
End Sub
```

The above will show the target and then write TextBox1.
If you need to keep another or the current sheet visible until `Zamknij` is clicked, here is another approach:

```
Option Explicit

'At the top of the userform (before any subs): Declare a module-level variable
Private mwsTarget As Worksheet

Private Sub Zamknij_Click()
    mwsTarget.Activate
    Unload Me
End Sub
Private Sub Sheet1_Click()
    ApplyToSheet Worksheets(1)
End Sub
Private Sub Sheet2_Click()
    ApplyToSheet Worksheets(2)
End Sub
Private Sub Sheet3_Click()
    ApplyToSheet Worksheets(3)
End Sub

Sub ApplyToSheet(wsSheet As Worksheet)
    Set mwsTarget = wsSheet
    wsSheet.Cells(1, 1) = TextBox1.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't you mean `Unload Me`? `Me.Unload` just gives an error.

Comment: Also, consider the possibility that a different workbook has been activated between clicking a "Sheet" button and closing the form.  Adding `mwsTarget.Parent.Activate` would be a wise precaution

Comment: @braX: Silly Me :) What I get for punching out code with one foot half out the door... Have fixed.

Comment: @chris neilsen: Yep... and many other things one could guess at. Have assumed the code in OP basically works (as they only asked about this one bit).